# Plotting a sequence of isosceles triangles of diminishing size

Tags: graphics, geometry

I try to plot the following graph using `Graphics` and `Table`. The graph consists of infinitely many isosceles triangles (without their bases).

The plot is within $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. The first isosceles triangle is of base $\frac{1}{2}$ and height $1$, the 2nd is of base $\frac{1}{4}$ and height $\frac{1}{2}$, etc. In general the $k$ th is of base length $2^{-k}$ and height $\frac{1}{k}$. There are infinitely many such triangles and the total base length is hence $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {{2^{ - k}}}  = 1$.

The code I tried is

```
linelist = Table[
   {{Boole[Mod[i, 2] == 0]*(1 - 2^(-i/2)) + 
      Boole[Mod[i, 2] == 1]*(1 - 2^(-(i + 1)/2) - 2^(-(i + 1)/2 - 1)),
      Boole[Mod[i, 2] == 0]*0 + Boole[Mod[i, 2] == 1]*2/(i + 1)}},
   {i, 1, 100}
   ];

Graphics[lineList, Axes -> True];
```

but something wrong occurs and the output is empty. I don't know what is wrong with the code.

Thank you!

The graph I want to plot is sketched as the following:

[image]

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried? It should be straightforward to find a formula for the coordinates of the maxima and minima, then you can just make as many as you need and use `ListPlot`.

Comment: There is a typo in your code `linelist` is not the same as `lineList`

Comment: Of course, you cannot actually make a plot with infinitely many triangles…

Comment: @J.M. Tony's original post said that, but for some reason Tony removed that observation.

Answer (score 12):

Another approach would be to consider the triangles as graphics primitives. The first triangle would be constructed manually with

```
Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1/4, 1}, {1/2, 0}}]
```

and each other triangle would be constructed by translating and scaling properly the first triangle. A set of triangles would be obtained with

```
myTriangles[number_] := NestList[
  {Scale[
  Translate[Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1/4, 1}, {1/2, 0}}], {(#[[2]] + 1)/2, 0}], 
  {#[[3]]/2, 1/(Denominator@#[[4]] + 1)}, {Left, Bottom}], 
  (#[[2]] + 1)/2, #[[3]]/2, 1/(Denominator@#[[4]] + 1)} &, 
  {Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1/4, 1}, {1/2, 0}}], 0, 1, 1}, number - 1][[All, 1]]
```

To plot 100 triangles we would use for instance

```
Graphics[myTriangles[100], Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

An alternative (perhaps cleaner) approach would be to use the MapThread function

```
myTranslations[number_] := Accumulate@NestList[#/2 &, 1/2, number - 1]
myScalingsX[number_] := NestList[#/2 &, 1/2, number - 1]
myScalingsY[number_] := NestList[1/(Denominator@# + 1) &, 1/2, number - 1]

myTrianglesFromMT[number_] := {Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1/4, 1}, {1/2, 0}}], MapThread[
   Scale[
   Translate[Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1/4, 1}, {1/2, 0}}], {#1, 0}], 
   {#2, #3}, {Left, Bottom}] &, 
   {myTranslations[number], myScalingsX[number], myScalingsY[number]}]}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
num=100

p = Partition[Accumulate@Prepend[NestList[#/2 &, 1/2, num - 1], 0], 2,1];
ListLinePlot[Join @@ MapThread[{{#1[[1]], 0}, {Mean[#1], #2}, {#1[[2]], 0}} &, 
   {p, 1/Range@Length@p}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Here is another couple of takes on the same problem. Both attempts construct a list of base points (in red in the plot below), and a separate list of apex points (in blue), then they `Riffle` the two lists together to get a list of points to plot with `ListPlot`.

The **first approach** uses `MovingAverage` to determine the $x$ position of the apex points:

```
nmax = 10;

basepoints = {#, 0} & /@ Join[{0}, Accumulate[Table[2^-n, {n, 1, nmax}]]]
apexpoints = MapIndexed[{#1, 1/First@#2} &, MovingAverage[%[[All, 1]], 2]]
allpoints = Riffle[basepoints, apexpoints]

ListPlot[
 allpoints,
 Filling -> Axis, Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 0.3, 
 PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Full,
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.01], Red, Point[basepoints], Blue, Point[apexpoints]}
]
```

[image: numerical results]

[image: corresponding plot]

---

The **second approach** uses direct formulae to calculate the positions of those points. The results, of course, are the same.

```
nmax = 10;

basepoints = Table[{1 - 2^-n, 0}, {n, 0, nmax + 1, 1}];
apexpoints = Table[{1 - 3 2^-(n + 2), 1/(n + 1)}, {n, 0, nmax, 1}];
allpoints = Riffle[basepoints, apexpoints];
```

Comment: MarcoB:   `allpoints = SortBy[Join[basepoints, apexpoints], First];` also works.

Answer (score 10):

[`GeometricTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricTransformation.html) is an efficient graphics tool for drawing many affine transforms of a figure.

```
Graphics[{
  LightGray, EdgeForm[Lighter@Blue],
  GeometricTransformation[
   Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1/2, 0}, {1/4, 1}}], 
   ScalingTransform[{2^(1 - #), 1/#}, {1, 0}] & /@ Range[100]
   ]},
 Frame -> True
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I quite like this... +1

Comment: @ciao, Thanks but if I hadn't started off on the wrong path, I would have used `ScalingTransform[{2^(1 - #), 1/#}, {1, 0}] & /@ Range[100]` from the start. :)

Answer (score 7):

```
g[n_] := Sum[1/2^i, {i, 1, n}];
f[n_] := (- 1/2^(n + 1) + g[n] )
t1 = Table[{f[n], 1/n}, {n, 1, 20}];
t2 = Table[{g[n], 0}, {n, 0, 20}];
t3 = Sort[Union[t1, t2]]
ListPlot[t3, Joined -> True, Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Triangle Plot]

You can try also with your code:

```
linelist = 
  Table[{Boole[Mod[i, 2] == 0]*(1 - 2^(-i/2)) + 
  Boole[Mod[i, 2] == 1]*(1 - 2^(-(i + 1)/2) - 2^(-(i + 1)/2 - 1)), 
  Boole[Mod[i, 2] == 0]*0 + Boole[Mod[i, 2] == 1]*2/(i + 1)}, {i, 1, 100}];    
(*Note removed {} *)
ListPlot[linelist, Joined -> True, Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
tr[x_] :=Abs[TriangleWave[x 2^-(Floor[Log[2, 1 - x]] + 1)]/(Floor[Log[2, 1 - x]])]
```

Visualizing:

```
Plot[tr[x], {x, 0, 1}, 
 GridLines -> {1 - PowerRange[1/2, 1/128, 1/2], Table[1/j, {j, 7}]}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, `PowerRange[]` is new… finally there's something like MATLAB's  `logspace()`. :)

Comment: @J.M. sometimes `PowerRange` handy...

Comment: BTW: `MantissaExponent[]` could also be used in your case.

Comment: @J.M. thanks! always learning something. Useful to know for the armamentarium

Answer (score 5):

```
heights = Table[1/(k 2^(k + 1)), {k, 1, 15}];
widthpositions = 
  Partition[Accumulate@Prepend[NestList[#/2 &, 1/2, 14], 0], 2, 1];
Plot[MapThread[#1 PDF[TriangularDistribution[#2], x] &, 
  {heights, widthpositions}], 
 {x, 0, 1}, 
 Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, using the PDF of a triangular distribution is quite nifty! (+1)

Answer (score 5):

<del>Untested</del> Just tested:

```
With[{n = 20},
     Plot[Sum[UnitTriangle[(x - 1) 2^(k + 1) + 3]/k, {k, n}], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

Here is a solution that is entirely equivalent to ubpdqn's:

```
Plot[Abs[TriangleWave[#1]/(#2 - 1)] & @@ MantissaExponent[1 - x, 2], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Tested and neat +1 :)

Comment: Thanks for testing! It was okay with *gedanken Mathematica*, so a confirmation was reassuring.

Comment: one day I hope to develop such a "gedanken" Mathematica alas my hardware is too old and you can't get upgrades...that is why I MSE provides a nice network to extend beyond ones constraints :)

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is nothing much wrong with your approach. You generate the coordinates for vertices you want to plot, but that's not enough. `Graphics` requires graphic primitives such as `Line` (the one to use in this case), so you need to wrap your coordinates in that primitive.

```
pts[max_Integer?EvenQ] :=
  Table[
    {Boole[Mod[i, 2] == 0]*(1 - 2^(-i/2)) + 
     Boole[Mod[i, 2] == 1]*(1 - 2^(-(i + 1)/2) - 2^(-(i + 1)/2 - 1)),
     Boole[Mod[i, 2] == 0]*0 + Boole[Mod[i, 2] == 1]*2/(i + 1)}, 
    {i,0, max}]

pts[4]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0}, {1/4, 1}, {1/2, 0}, {5/8, 1/2}, {3/4, 0}}
> ```

```
Graphics[Line[pts[12]], Axes -> True]
```

[image: plot]

Another minor error you made was to write

```
{{
  Boole[Mod[i, 2] == 0]*(1 - 2^(-i/2)) + 
  Boole[Mod[i, 2] == 1]*(1 - 2^(-(i + 1)/2) - 2^(-(i + 1)/2 - 1)),
  Boole[Mod[i, 2] == 0]*0 + Boole[Mod[i, 2] == 1]*2/(i + 1)}
}}
```

when all you needed was

```
{
  Boole[Mod[i, 2] == 0]*(1 - 2^(-i/2)) + 
  Boole[Mod[i, 2] == 1]*(1 - 2^(-(i + 1)/2) - 2^(-(i + 1)/2 - 1)),
  Boole[Mod[i, 2] == 0]*0 + Boole[Mod[i, 2] == 1]*2/(i + 1)
}
```

Comment: Of course, for an integer `i`, `Boole[Mod[i, 2] == 1]` is simply `Mod[i, 2]`.